# Nesting functions that accept protocols as types in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I am teaching myself Swift and I have come across a problem that I do not quite understand. I am using the official Swift manual. In the manual there is a protocol named `Shape` that has one requirement:

```
protocol Shape {
    func draw() -> String
}
```

There is a struct called `Triangle` which conforms to `Shape`, from which we will create a variable called `smallTriangle`:

```
struct Triangle: Shape {
    var size: Int
    
    func draw() -> String {
        var result = [String]()
        for length in 1...size {
            result.append(String(repeating: "*", count: length))
        }
        return result.joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}

let smallTriangle = Triangle(size: 3)
```

There is a generic struct named `FlippedShape` that conforms to `Shape` that accepts a generic parameter `T` that also conforms to `Shape`. The struct flips any shape that is passed to it:

```
struct FlippedShape<T: Shape>: Shape {
    var shape: T
    
    func draw() -> String {
        let lines = shape.draw().split(separator: "\n")
        return lines.reversed().joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}
```

There is a generic function called `protoFlip` which has a generic parameter `T` that conforms to `Shape` and has a return type of `Shape`, an instance of `FlippedShape` to be specific:

```
func protoFlip<T: Shape>(_ shape: T) -> Shape {
    return FlippedShape(shape: shape)
}
```

An attempt to pass small triangle to this function and nest it results in an error:

```
protoFlip(protoFlip(smallTriangle))
```

The manual says that it is because:

> "The result of flipping a triangle is a value of type Shape, and the
> `protoFlip(_:)` function takes an argument of some type that conforms to
> the Shape protocol. However, a value of a protocol type doesn’t conform to
> that protocol; the value returned by `protoFlip(_:)` doesn’t conform to
> Shape. This means code like `protoFlip(protoFlip(smallTriange))` that
> applies multiple transformations is invalid because the flipped shape isn’t a valid argument to `protoFlip(_:)`."

I can't say I understand why this is so. The `protoFlip` function accepts a generic parameter of type `Shape`, and returns an instance that conforms to `Shape`, so why exactly would that instance that is returned be considered an invalid argument to `protoFlip`? I especially didn't understand the phrase ***"However, a value of a protocol type doesn’t conform to that protocol".*** What does this mean?

Comment: Protocols don't conform to protocols, including themselves. So, when `protoFlip` returns a `Shape`, that doesn't fit with what its parameter needs, which is a type conforming to `Shape`, but `Shape` doesn't conform to `Shape`. Instead, `protoFlip` should return `some Shape` - which is called an opaque type, but what it means is that it's some type that conforms to `Shape` as will be defined by the function (callee)

Comment: See Hamish's answer in the duplicate.